# How to split numbers in string?

Tags: python, split

For example :

```
je = ("3,5&6,7")
```

And the result that I want is [3,5,6,7]

What I have tried so far:

```
je = ("3,5&6,7")
jean = je.split(",")
j = str(jean)
De = j.split("&")
print De
```

But my result is ["['3', '5", "6', '7']"]

​

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `replace()` along with [`ast.literal_eval`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
>>> import ast
>>> je = ("3,5&6,7")
>>> ast.literal_eval(je.replace('&', ','))
(3, 5, 6, 7)
```

Or if you really need a list:

```
>>> ast.literal_eval('['+je.replace('&', ',')+']')
[3, 5, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `regex`:

```
In [3]: import re

In [4]: strs = "3,5&6,7"
#map
In [5]: map(int, re.findall(r'\d+',strs))
Out[5]: [3, 5, 6, 7]
#LC
In [6]: [int(x) for x in  re.findall(r'\d+',strs)]
Out[6]: [3, 5, 6, 7]
```